# Group structure on $[X, \Omega^{2}(Y)]$ is abelian

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm very begginer when it comes to algebraic topology. I have no idea how to  prove (firstly see why it could be true or even start) this statement:
Composition of loops gives the structure of group on $[X,\Omega(Y)]$ (Yes, I see this). We define $\Omega^{2}(Y)=\Omega(\Omega(Y))$. Prove that group structure on  $[X,\Omega^{2}(Y)]$ is abelian.
I would be thankful for help.

Comment: Use the loop space - suspension adjunction and look at the proof that $\pi_2$ is abelian.

Comment: You want the Eckmann-Hilton argument.

Comment: The Eckmann-Hilton  argument is perhaps better called a use of the "interchange law", since that is used more generally.